# Selfbot sending 2 messages instead of 1 | discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

Hello I am developing a auto owo selfbot on discord and when I run the script it sends 1 message twice so here's the code

```
async def autoowo(ctx, *, num):
    await ctx.send("DEATH X AUTO OWO ENABLED")
    if num == None:
        await ctx.send("Provide a number of how much it will coinflip")
    await ctx.send(f"owo cf {num}")
    asyncio.sleep(1)
    await ctx.send("owo h")
    asyncio.sleep(1)
    await ctx.send("owo b")
    asyncio.sleep(1)
    await ctx.send(f"owo cf {num}")
    asyncio.sleep(1)
    await ctx.send("owo h")
    asyncio.sleep(1)
    await ctx.send("owo b")
    asyncio.sleep(1)
    await ctx.send(f"owo cf {num}")
    asyncio.sleep(1)
    await ctx.send("owo h")
    asyncio.sleep(1)
    await ctx.send("owo b")
    asyncio.sleep(1)
    await ctx.send(f"owo cf {num}")
    asyncio.sleep(1)
    await ctx.send("owo h")
    asyncio.sleep(1)
    await ctx.send("owo b")
    asyncio.sleep(1)
    await ctx.send(f"owo cf {num}")
    asyncio.sleep(1)
    await ctx.send("owo h")
    asyncio.sleep(1)
    await ctx.send("owo b")
    asyncio.sleep(1)
    await ctx.send(f"owo cf {num}")
    asyncio.sleep(1)
    await ctx.send("owo h")
    asyncio.sleep(1)
    await ctx.send("owo b")
    asyncio.sleep(1)
    await ctx.send(f"owo cf {num}")
    asyncio.sleep(1)
    await ctx.send("owo h")
    asyncio.sleep(1)
    await ctx.send("owo b")
    asyncio.sleep(1)
    await ctx.send(f"owo cf {num}")
    asyncio.sleep(1)
    await ctx.send("owo h")
    asyncio.sleep(1)
    await ctx.send("owo b")
    asyncio.sleep(1)
    await ctx.send(f"owo cf {num}")
    asyncio.sleep(1)
    await ctx.send("owo h")
    asyncio.sleep(1)
    await ctx.send("owo b")
    asyncio.sleep(1)
    await ctx.send(f"owo cf {num}")
    asyncio.sleep(1)
    await ctx.send("owo h")
    asyncio.sleep(1)
    await ctx.send("owo b")
    asyncio.sleep(1)
    await ctx.send(f"owo cf {num}")
    asyncio.sleep(1)
    await ctx.send("owo h")
    asyncio.sleep(1)
    await ctx.send("owo b")
    asyncio.sleep(1)
    await ctx.send(f"owo cf {num}")
    asyncio.sleep(1)
    await ctx.send("owo h")
    asyncio.sleep(1)
    await ctx.send("owo b")
    asyncio.sleep(1)
    await ctx.send(f"owo cf {num}")
    asyncio.sleep(1)
    await ctx.send("owo h")
    asyncio.sleep(1)
    await ctx.send("owo b")
    asyncio.sleep(1)
    await ctx.send(f"owo cf {num}")
    asyncio.sleep(1)
    await ctx.send("owo h")
    asyncio.sleep(1)
    await ctx.send("owo b")
    asyncio.sleep(1)
    await ctx.send(f"owo cf {num}")
    asyncio.sleep(1)
    await ctx.send("owo h")
    asyncio.sleep(1)
    await ctx.send("owo b")
    asyncio.sleep(1)
    await ctx.send(f"owo cf {num}")
    asyncio.sleep(1)
    await ctx.send("owo h")
    asyncio.sleep(1)
    await ctx.send("owo b")
    asyncio.sleep(1)
    await ctx.send(f"owo cf {num}")
    asyncio.sleep(1)
    await ctx.send("owo h")
    asyncio.sleep(1)
    await ctx.send("owo b")
    asyncio.sleep(1)
    await ctx.send(f"owo cf {num}")
    asyncio.sleep(1)
    await ctx.send("owo h")
    asyncio.sleep(1)
    await ctx.send("owo b")
    asyncio.sleep(1)
    await ctx.send(f"owo cf {num}")
    asyncio.sleep(1)
    await ctx.send("owo h")
    asyncio.sleep(1)
    await ctx.send("owo b")
    asyncio.sleep(1)
    await ctx.send(f"owo cf {num}")
    asyncio.sleep(1)
    await ctx.send("owo h")
    asyncio.sleep(1)
    await ctx.send("owo b")
    asyncio.sleep(1)
    await ctx.send(f"owo cf {num}")
    asyncio.sleep(1)
    await ctx.send("owo h")
    asyncio.sleep(1)
    await ctx.send("owo b")
    asyncio.sleep(1)
    await ctx.send(f"owo cf {num}")
    asyncio.sleep(1)
    await ctx.send("owo h")
    asyncio.sleep(1)
    await ctx.send("owo b")
    asyncio.sleep(1)
    await ctx.send(f"owo cf {num}")
    asyncio.sleep(1)
    await ctx.send("owo h")
    asyncio.sleep(1)
    await ctx.send("owo b")
    asyncio.sleep(1)
    await ctx.send(f"owo cf {num}")
    asyncio.sleep(1)
    await ctx.send("owo h")
    asyncio.sleep(1)
    await ctx.send("owo b")
    asyncio.sleep(1)
    await ctx.send(f"owo cf {num}")
    asyncio.sleep(1)
    await ctx.send("owo h")
    asyncio.sleep(1)
    await ctx.send("owo b")
    asyncio.sleep(1)
    await ctx.send(f"owo cf {num}")
    asyncio.sleep(1)
    await ctx.send("owo h")
    asyncio.sleep(1)
    await ctx.send("owo b")
    asyncio.sleep(1)
    await ctx.send(f"owo cf {num}")
    asyncio.sleep(1)
    await ctx.send("owo h")
    asyncio.sleep(1)
    await ctx.send("owo b")
    asyncio.sleep(1)
    await ctx.send(f"owo cf {num}")
    asyncio.sleep(1)
    await ctx.send("owo h")
    asyncio.sleep(1)
    await ctx.send("owo b")
    asyncio.sleep(1)
    await ctx.send(f"owo cf {num}")
    asyncio.sleep(1)
    await ctx.send("owo h")
    asyncio.sleep(1)
    await ctx.send("owo b")
    asyncio.sleep(1)
    await ctx.send(f"owo cf {num}")
    asyncio.sleep(1)
    await ctx.send("owo h")
    asyncio.sleep(1)
    await ctx.send("owo b")
    asyncio.sleep(1)
    await ctx.send(f"owo cf {num}")
    asyncio.sleep(1)
    await ctx.send("owo h")
    asyncio.sleep(1)
    await ctx.send("owo b")
    asyncio.sleep(1)
    await ctx.send(f"owo cf {num}")
    asyncio.sleep(1)
    await ctx.send("owo h")
    asyncio.sleep(1)
    await ctx.send("owo b")
    asyncio.sleep(1)
    await ctx.send(f"owo cf {num}")
    asyncio.sleep(1)
    await ctx.send("owo h")
    asyncio.sleep(1)
    await ctx.send("owo b")
    asyncio.sleep(1)
    await ctx.send(f"owo cf {num}")
    asyncio.sleep(1)
    await ctx.send("owo h")
    asyncio.sleep(1)
    await ctx.send("owo b")
    asyncio.sleep(1)
    await ctx.send(f"owo cf {num}")
    asyncio.sleep(1)
    await ctx.send("owo h")
    asyncio.sleep(1)
    await ctx.send("owo b")
    asyncio.sleep(1)
    await ctx.send(f"owo cf {num}")
    asyncio.sleep(1)
    await ctx.send("owo h")
    asyncio.sleep(1)
    await ctx.send("owo b")
    asyncio.sleep(1)
    await ctx.send(f"owo cf {num}")
    asyncio.sleep(1)
    await ctx.send("owo h")
    asyncio.sleep(1)
    await ctx.send("owo b")
    asyncio.sleep(1)
    await ctx.send(f"owo cf {num}")
    asyncio.sleep(1)
    await ctx.send("owo h")
    asyncio.sleep(1)
    await ctx.send("owo b")
    asyncio.sleep(1)
    await ctx.send(f"owo cf {num}")
    asyncio.sleep(1)
    await ctx.send("owo h")
    asyncio.sleep(1)
    await ctx.send("owo b")
    asyncio.sleep(1)
    await ctx.send(f"owo cf {num}")
    asyncio.sleep(1)
    await ctx.send("owo h")
    asyncio.sleep(1)
    await ctx.send("owo b")
    asyncio.sleep(1)
    await ctx.send(f"owo cf {num}")
    asyncio.sleep(1)
    await ctx.send("owo h")
    asyncio.sleep(1)
    await ctx.send("owo b")
    asyncio.sleep(1)
```

I even developed a kill switch if this happens again but it didn't do anything but just did the same thing I mean it shutdowned the selfbot and when I restarted it and did the auto owo command again it didn't work

The kill switch code:

````
@deathx.command()
async def sĥutdown(ctx):
    await ctx.bot.logout()
    print(Fore.RED + "shutdowned the selfbot")```
````

Comment: it is unclear what you mean by "it sends 1 message twice"

Comment: I think you should read through the [mcve] page. There's a lot of code here that doesn't look relevant to the issue.

Comment: what's even the purpose of that code? Why instead of using a for loop you're copying & pasting the same line(s) over and over?

Answer (score 3):

"*Automating normal user accounts (generally called "self-bots") outside of the OAuth2/bot API is **forbidden**, and can result in an account termination if found.*" -  [Discord Trust & Safety Team](https://support.discord.com/hc/en-us/articles/115002192352-Automated-user-accounts-self-bots-)

So, self-bots are forbidden in the discord, also helping about self-bots is a no-go in the community rules of the library you are using. You should make a proper bot via a **bot account**.